# How fix permanently: Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-8.0

I am working with `Ubuntu` 18.04 and `MySQL Server` - 8.0.18

Suddenly today MySQL can't start anymore

With the `sudo service mysql status` command appears:

```
sudo service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-11-02 17:05:23 -05; 1min 44s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 1659 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 1620 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1659 (code=exited, status=2)
   Status: "Server startup in progress"

Nov 02 17:05:22 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Nov 02 17:05:22 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 17:05:22 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Nov 02 17:05:23 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 02 17:05:23 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 9.
Nov 02 17:05:23 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Nov 02 17:05:23 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 02 17:05:23 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 17:05:23 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

With the `sudo service mysql restart` command appears:

```
sudo service mysql restart
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Following and executing the two suggested commands:

- `systemctl status mysql.service`
- `journalctl -xe`

Therefore: `sudo systemctl status mysql.service`

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-11-02 17:08:21 -05; 38s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 2633 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 2594 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2633 (code=exited, status=2)
   Status: "Server startup in progress"

Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Nov 02 17:08:21 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 02 17:08:21 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 02 17:08:21 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Nov 02 17:08:21 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 02 17:08:21 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 17:08:21 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

And with `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 audit[2632]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=2632 comm="apparmor_p
Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 audit[2633]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" pid=2633 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122
Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 audit[2633]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/2633/task/2634/mem" pid=2633 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid
Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 02 17:08:20 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Nov 02 17:08:21 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 02 17:08:21 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
```

I followed the solution about this post:

- [Can't start MySQL server (database corruption)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008298/cant-start-mysql-server-database-corruption)

I used the `innodb_force_recovery = 10` (ten), it playing, because with 1 and 2 did not work

Therefore with the `sudo systemctl start mysql` command is possible start the server. 
I can see all the data and users saved in peace.

Now through the `sudo systemctl status mysql` command I get

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-11-02 17:26:48 -05; 11s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 2769 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2808 (mysqld)
   Status: "Server is operational"
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 4617)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─2808 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Nov 02 17:26:47 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Nov 02 17:26:48 asus2016-vb01 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Until this point would has no sense this post, but if I do either Alpha or Beta steps:

```
Alpha (steps): 
sudo systemctl stop mysql
remove innodb_force_recovery = 10
sudo systemctl start mysql         

Beta (steps):
restart the PC, 
(I can confirm `MySQL` was started), 
remove innodb_force_recovery = 10
restart the PC
```

the same problem happens again.

Therefore now is mandatory keep the `innodb_force_recovery = 10`, otherwise it returns to the same problem

**Warning:**

According with:

- [15.21.2 Forcing InnoDB Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)
- [Corrupt InnoDB: Start mysqld only innodb_force_recovery=6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120864/corrupt-innodb-start-mysqld-only-innodb-force-recovery-6)

The correct range is from 1 to 6, I am assuming 10 is "interpreted" how the maximum value (6)

Is there a way to configure something and remove `innodb_force_recovery`? It to return to the normal or old configuration where all worked fine (without `innodb_force_recovery`)

**Note** the final content of `/var/log/mysql/error.log` is

```
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2019-11-02T23:24:37.346875Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18) starting as process 1668
2019-11-02T23:24:37.804662Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012671] [InnoDB] Encryption algorithm support missing: N
2019-11-02T23:24:37.804783Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: log0recv.cc:3563:err == DB_SUCCESS thread 139850038036224
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
23:24:37 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x555c74a041c0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f315fd6bce0 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x555c72ab2edd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x303) [0x555c71b5bc63]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f317319a890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7f31712d3e97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f31712d5801]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x2ec) [0x555c72d6015c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2074038) [0x555c72c1d038]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(recv_recovery_from_checkpoint_start(log_t&, unsigned long)+0x660) [0x555c72c26e40]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_start(bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)+0x1741) [0x555c72d0e701]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1fe3f25) [0x555c72b8cf25]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::DDSE_dict_init(THD*, dict_init_mode_t, unsigned int)+0x9f) [0x555c72868f5f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::upgrade_57::do_pre_checks_and_initialize_dd(THD*)+0x5b4) [0x555c72a7d8f4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1076dc5) [0x555c71c1fdc5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x24182b9) [0x555c72fc12b9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db) [0x7f317318f6db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7f31713b688f]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I am working with VirtualBox - Ubuntu is a guest. It had been working for more of 3 months, now suddenly this situation appeared.

Comment: Do ypu made a backup recentyl and used this only as test. Virtual box are file, now and then errors happen in the filesystem, further you also should check the harddrive for errors. (S.m.a.r.t and filesystemcheck)

Comment: @nbk I remember now that I had this situation since I lost internet connection, and I restarted Ubuntu. Seems behind the scenes MySQL was affected

Comment: I get this anytime mysql upgrade/update doesn't go through succesfully. I've resolved this couple of times but stuck this time

Comment: I have never resolved this ... sadly was mandatory re install MySQL, and **disable** the _auto-startup_ feature.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and this might help. I was running my server on aws and downgraded the instance to a server with less memory (512mb) and it seems mysql requires minimum 1gb so you might want to check you have enough ram memory.

Comment: My case was about a failed startup process of Ubuntu, something was damaged. My solution was to uninstall and install again MySQL, of course all data was lost. But it was about to development, not for production. Lesson, have disabled auto startup of MySQL in Ubuntu

Comment: In my case it turned out that the disk was full. Deleting some unnecessary files obviously helped.

Comment: aws is bad service provider, never recommend or use it ,digital ocean has no issues, aws make this issues to collect more money